# How to prove a function which is polynomial in the coordinates is differentiable everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:
**Using the chain rule** to prove that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is polynomial in the coordinates is differentiable everywhere.

(The chain rule is for the use under function composition circumstances, how to apply it here to prove that the function f which is polynomial in the coordinates is differentiable everywhere?)

Comment: I'd rather suggest *sum* and *product* rule. Then again, the product rule is an application of the chain rule (If we let $p(x,y)=xy$, then $f(x)g(x)$ is just $p\circ(f,g)$ and hence has derivative $f'p_x+g'p_y$)

Comment: If your function looks like this
$$
f(\mathbf x) = \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q = 0}^{k_p}a_{pq}x_p^q
$$
where $\mathbf x = \left [x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_p,\ldots,x_n \right ]^T$, $k_p$ is order of polynomial for $p^{th}$ coordinate then it is differentiable everywhere. But probably that's not it, because it's not clear where to apply chain rule either. Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "polynomial in the coordinates"?

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting. First of all, the question @Kaster poses is relevant: what do you mean by polynomial in the coordinates? For now, we'll assume the same as he did, namely that each monomial occuring in $f$ contains at most one variable $x_i$.

From now on, we will assume $f$ has degree $d$ and we will write 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{d} a_{ij} x_i^j .$$
The question asks you to use the chain rule in order to prove it's differentiable. This seems a bit elaborate, but basically asks to split this map in parts (i.e. $f=f_r\circ f_{r=1}\circ\ldots\circ f_1$) of which we already know they are differentiable. It then follows from the chain rule that their composition $f$ is differentiable.

As mentioned, this may be somewhat elaborate. We will just assume that $x\mapsto x^m$ and $x\mapsto ax$ are known to be differentiable ($m\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$) and that matrix multiplication is differentiable as well (if you don't like this, you could use the sum rule instead). The map $f$ can then be split as
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_1^d\\\vdots & \ddots & & \vdots\\\vdots& & \ddots & \vdots\\1 & x_n & \ldots & x_n^d\end{array}\right) \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1\cdot a_{10} & a_{11}x_1 & \ldots & a_{1d}x_1^d\\\vdots & \ddots & & \vdots\\\vdots& & \ddots & \vdots\\1\cdot a_{n0} & a_{n1}x_n & \ldots & a_{nd}x_n^d\end{array}\right)\\
\mapsto(1,\ldots,1)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1\cdot a_{10} & a_{11}x_1 & \ldots & a_{1d}x_1^d\\\vdots & \ddots & & \vdots\\\vdots& & \ddots & \vdots\\1\cdot a_{n0} & a_{n1}x_n & \ldots & a_{nd}x_n^d\end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\\vdots\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right). $$

If you ensure the $a_{ij}$ are numbered correctly (if your convention seems to be wrong, you may try to transpose everything) and the correct number of ones in the final step, the composite is well-defined and corresponds to $f$. Moreover, it only contains steps of the form we assumed to know to be differentiable and therefore $f$, their composite, is differentiable as well.

I hope this is more or less what you wanted/needed. A few remarks need to be made, though.

*Remark 1.* All the coefficients with $j=0$ correspond to the constant term of $f$. You may take all of them, possibly except for one, to be zero if you like, but this is not necessary.

*Remark 2.* I started by assuming a meaning of "polynomial in coordinates". There are other things you could've meant. The first two things I tried, however, contradicted your statement. If you meant $f(0,\ldots,0,x_i,0,\ldots,0)$ to be a polynomial for each $i$, a counterexample is given by $n=2$, $f(x,y)= |x|y$. If you meant that $f(1,\ldots,1,x_i,1,\ldots,1)$ is polynomial for all $i$, $n=2$, $f(x,y)=(1-y)|x|$ is a counterexample.